# Python - utility program to check module availability

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a command line(preferably) utility program that lists all `major` versions of python that come bundled with a particular module in that version's library?

For example `json` module is only available in versions 2.6+

So running this utility should list:

```
2.6
2.7
.. and the 3.x versions
```

Comment: Do you mean a list of the modules **in the standard library** per version?

Comment: No, I want the inverse. Given a module, list which versions of python have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such built-in command.

If having an internet connection is not an issue you can simply check the url at `https://docs.python.org/<version-number>/library/<module-name>.html`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError


def has_module(version, module_name):
    try:
        urlopen('https://docs.python.org/{}/library/{}.html'.format(version, module_name))
    except HTTPError as e:
        if e.code == 404:
            return False
        raise e
    return True
```

Example usage:

```
In [2]: has_module('2.7', 'asyncio')
Out[2]: False

In [3]: has_module('3.3', 'asyncio')
Out[3]: False

In [4]: has_module('3.4', 'asyncio')
Out[4]: True
```

Must be run in python3, but a python2 version isn't hard to write.

If you want an offline tool you can always parse the page `https://docs.python.org/<version-number>/library/index.html` and obtain a list of module pages for that python version and then just build a `dict` that maps the python version to the set of available modules.

Comment: What if you get a server error? e.code will then not equal 404 and the function returns true.

Comment: @Marichyasana The function does *not* return true. It just raises the error (that's what the `raise e` does). When using that function you should check for other errors and just print "server down" or something. That's the downside of a solution that relies on an internet connection...